# Returning data in Angular2 FINAL service to Component

Tags: angular

I have a service with a `login` function.

```
export class AuthService {
   login(email:string, password: string) {
      this.firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(value => {
          return value;
      }).catch(err => {
          return err;
      });
   }
}
```

And I'm calling it in a component

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    login() {
       this.auth.login(this.email, this.password);
       this.email = this.password = '';
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I get what is returned from the login function in the service in the component and get the component to wait until the service has actually returned the value?

Side Note: I'm not used to typescript at all.

Comment: At first the service should return a Observable or promise . For that change the code slightly like `return this.firebaseAuth`.Then in component get the results by `this.auth.login(this.email, this.password).then(Result => console.log(Result));`

Comment: So that would make it so you could something like `.then(value => {...` in the component function?

Comment: @Rajez would you like to put that in an answer so I can mark it complete?

Comment: Yes I will put it in answer

Comment: You forgot to inject your authservice in your constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first the service should return a Observable or promise . For that change the code slightly like `return this.firebaseAuth`.Then in component get the results by `this.auth.login(this.email, this.password).then(Result => console.log(Result))`